# Identify alternate dates in .NET (in PowerShell, C# or VB)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, date, math

What's the easiest way to perform an operation based on alternate dates?

Basically, I have 2 folders (***dir1*** & ***dir2***) on Azure file storage, in which files need to be copied (over-written) on daily basis - one day in 'dir1', next day in 'dir2'.

I'm trying to write this in PowerShell (but happy with your answers in C# or VB).

I tried even/odd dates logic, but it breaks if month ends on 31st - because next date i.e. 1st is also an odd number (same problem with day-of-year as after 365 comes 1st both being odd numbers).

```
if((Get-Date).Day % 2 -eq 0 ) {"copy files in dir1"} else {"copy files in dir2"}
```

OR

```
if((Get-Date).DayOfYear % 2 -eq 0 ) {"copy files in dir1"} else {"copy files in dir2"}
```

I guess another method could be to read the "*Last-Modified*" file-attribute, but I'm struggling to read this as the containing folders reside on Azure cloud (in Azure File Storage).

I will appreciate any ideas.
TIA

Comment: the best way would be reading the file dates and overwriting the oldest set. since you can't get that data reliably [and i have no ideas on that], you may simply need to add a file to each dir with a timestamped file name.

Comment: @EddieKumar - Any chance you could select an answer as correct? That is how SO works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of *day of month* or *day of year*, you could use *day since some fixed time point*:

```
int totalDays = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)).TotalDays;
if (totalDays % 2 == 0) { }
else { }
```

Comment: Thanks @dymanoid,  I will try this, write it in PowerShell and post the code as answer here. Ta..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in PowerShell. I applied even/odd logic on the "number of days", which is calculated/generated by ***subtracting current-date with a fixed-date*** (as others suggested), I have written+tested it in PowerShell and can confirm it's working fine.

`if(((Get-Date)-[DateTime]'2018-01-01').Days % 2) {'use dir1'} else{'use dir2'}`

OR

```
$fixedDate = (Get-Date "01/01/2018")
$today = (Get-Date)
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Start $fixedDate -End $today
if(($ts).Days % 2 -eq 0) {"copy files in dir1"} else {"copy files in dir2"}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just calculate the number of days since a fixed point in time and use that to determine even or odd.

```
if (((Get-Date) - [DateTime]'1970-01-01').Days % 2) {
    Write-Host 'odd day'
} else {
    Write-Host 'even day'
}
```